# Sqlite statements for iOS

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am trying to create a table with a number of columns.  I am trying to bind the value (which is a variable) to create the table name.  I keep getting an error: ('Error while creating update statement. 'near "?": syntax error'') So obviously I am doing something wrong with trying to bind it. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

```
- (void)addTable{

     NSString *cat = sourceName;

     if(addtablestmt == nil) {

    const char *sqlStr = "CREATE Table ? ('itemID' 'integer','itemName' 'char(50)','itemCategory' 'char(50)','itemCount' 'integer','itemDone' 'char(50)','itemNote' 'char(50)','itemOrder' 'char(50)',PRIMARY KEY (itemID))";


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStr, -1, &addtablestmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_bind_text(addtablestmt, 1, [cat UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addtablestmt)){
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }

    sqlite3_reset(addtablestmt);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that sqlite supports dynamic table creation like this?

Comment: I thought it supported it but I may be going down the wrong road here.

Comment: I'm way out of my element here (haven't done and dynamic sql for many years), but usually you build dynamic queries or update statements, as opposed to dynamic table creation.  Poke around SO here, there's an amazing amount of codified experience.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something more like:

```
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE Table %@ ('itemID' 'integer','itemName' 'char(50)','itemCategory' 'char(50)','itemCount' 'integer','itemDone' 'char(50)','itemNote' 'char(50)','itemOrder' 'char(50)',PRIMARY KEY (itemID))", sourceName];

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStr UTF8String], -1, &addtablestmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind table name as a parameter. If you are planning on doing that, then you need to dynamically create the string as suggested by Joe. However be careful as that approach could lead to sql injection attacks. For ex a user could enter a name "; Delete from sqlite_master".